# Laravel - 5.8 background job uses global php.ini file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am trying to se Laravel background. I have followed the official doc for creating it, Job file:

```
    public function handle(){

    $fileGet = file_get_contents ('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff');
    return;
}

public function failed($exception)
{
    shell_exec(" php -i | grep 'Configuration File'");
    $fp = file_put_contents (base_path() . '/errors.txt', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path'));
}
```

I am using simple `file_get_contents`. This job is executed through `HTTP` request, when I access specific URL, Controller action:

```
CustomJob::dispatch();
```

, but I am getting this error:

> ErrorException: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /.../CustomJob.php:45

Everywhere in the hosting (shared) this option is enabled and I can use it WITHOUT Background jobs. The problem is when I use it in background job. The `errors.file` says about `php.ini` file - `/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.ini`

Now, I am using `php 7.3` with local (for the home dir) `php.ini` file.

I even can't debug that error, but how background job uses another `php.ini` file and is there a way to set the correct `php.ini` file ?

Answer (score 2):

Background jobs are probably fired using a seprate PHP CLI installation. Those are configured with separate php.ini files. You should try editing that one instead.

Comment: How, I can't understand ?

Comment: That depends on what your shared hosting offers you. Can you access the server via ssh? Can you adjust the php.ini config that way? Otherwise can you change the php.ini config in the control panel of your hosting?

Comment: Yes, I have accces. In cPanel this option is enabled.

Comment: Do you have access to a single php.ini config or two php.ini configs in cPanel. You will most likely only have acces to one; the one being used to serve web requests. The php.ini configuration which is used on the command line is the one you want, can you also access that one?

Comment: I have access in cPanel to local php.ini which is in my home dir

Comment: You'll have to figure out if that is only used for web requests or also for cli. One way would be to have a cli application run `phpinfo()` and see if the settings displayed match the ones set in the php.ini in your home dir

Comment: There are different. Actually, I have and cron job, which executes the code with `file_get_contents`, and the cron job is inside that background job, but for the simplicity of the question, I have removed that part. It is not important, because `file_get_contents`, doesn't work inside background job, BUT it works inside cron job, only. I can go in `SHH` and type the command `php artisan my_command` and it will work. Even, I can attach cron job to specific URL and still will work, the problem is when it is inside bg job with or without cron.